# AVFoundation Camera in less light mode

Tags: ios, camera

Hello in my application i am using custom camera using avfoundation. But in dark mode custom camera is bit darker then IOS camera application. I tried below code but didn't get any result

```
if ([device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance]) {
    NSLog(@"Enabling ContinuousAutoWhiteBalance");
    [device lockForConfiguration:&deviceError];
    device.whiteBalanceMode = AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance;
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

You can output of image in attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: From iOS8 you can change the exposure time, there a wonderfull WWDC 2014 video about it Camera Capture Manual Control https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/